# Cannot get post route to work in angular/node.js

Tags: node.js, angular

For some reason I cannot get my post route to work in my app, though it works just fine in Postman for some reason.

Here is my Node Server post route:

```
app.route('/submit-supplies').post((req, res) => {
    res.send(201, req.body);
})
```

Here is my service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SuppliesService {
    public url = environment.url;

    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({})
    };

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

    onSubmitSupplies(value) {
        console.log(value);
        return this.http.post(this.url + `submit-supplies`, value);
    }

}
```

And here is my component that is calling the service:

```
 supplyList: FormGroup;

  constructor(private supplyService: SuppliesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.supplyList = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      address1: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      address2: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      zipCode: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      suppliesNeeded: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
      // content: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])

    });

  }

  onSupplySubmit(){
    return this.supplyService.onSubmitSupplies(this.supplyList.value).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('hello');
    })
  }
```

So what is being sent is form data. The console.log in the onSubmitSupplies() function in the service does log out what I want it to. But it doesn't get to my server post route.

Instead I get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/submit-supplies' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add on your node server before your post this:

```
const app = expess();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
next();
});
```

If you don't use all this methods you remove them from  Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Comment: Ok that worked, I must have been missing something. Thank you!

Comment: @testersontesting great! If you can set it as answer and upvote!